# Rally API create ConversationPost

Tags: api, google-apps-script, post, rally, payload

with the following code I'm trying to create new conversation post for Capability. But it says

Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '{' but saw '' [ chars read = >>><<< ]

```
function createPost(objId, post) {
  objId = "313878829904";
  post = "<p>MindMap:Hello from GAS.</p>"
  var url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/conversationpost/create";
  
  var payload = {
    "ConversationPost": {
      "Artifact": "/portfolioitem/capability/" + objId,
      "Text": post
    }
  }
  
  var method = "POST";
  var options = optionsPost_(method, payload);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, optionsPost_(method, options));
  var content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  content.CreateResult.Errors.forEach(error => Logger.log(error));
}

function optionsPost_(method, payload) {
  var rallyApiKey = "";
  if (rallyApiKey != "") {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("RallyApiKey", rallyApiKey);
  } else {
    rallyApiKey = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("RallyApiKey");
  }

  if (rallyApiKey == null) return null;

  return {
    headers: { "ZSESSIONID": rallyApiKey },
    payload: payload,
    method: method
  };
}
```

I can't spot any problem.
Could you please help?
Thank you!
Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that from your error message, the payload might be required to be sent as JSON data. If my guessing is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
return {
  headers: { "ZSESSIONID": rallyApiKey },
  payload: payload,
  method: method
};
```

To:

```
return {
  headers: { "ZSESSIONID": rallyApiKey },
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  method: method,
  contentType: "application/json"
};
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the values of `payload` and `rallyApiKey` are valid values for using the API. Please be careful this.
- When above modification was not the dierct solution of your issue, can you provide the official document of API you want to use? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params) of Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @Petr Sedláček Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I noticed that you are posting your current situation as an answer. I would like to recommend to add it to your question. And, about the official document, I cannot see it because I have no account. I apologize for this. Do you have any other documents for about the API you want to use? And also, from the official document, I would like to confirm about the format of `payload` and `headers` for requesting.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Thank you for quick response. I'm sorry I didn't realize the documentation is accessible only after log in to the account... I didn't find it generally available so I assume I can't share it. I'll try to ask support in case I find a contact.

Comment: This could maybe help?
https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/57596/ws-api-request-examples-using-curl-and-b.html

Comment: @Petr Sedláček Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue had already been resolved. I'm glad for it. When I saw your added answer, it seems that your answer is the same with my proposed answer. So I cannot understand about `the problem was caused by combination of mistakes.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of difference between your added answer and my proposed answer? I would like to confirm it and study from it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. I'm sure your English is much better than mine. As I was desperate I did more than one change at the time, so I think I applied what you suggested, in the same time I involved other problem into my code. I also think that I copy pasted some non-printable characters as I searched for the solution on the internet. I spent some time to identify, where was a problem but I could not find it, therefore I'm sure you provided correct solution. I selected your post as the resolution for my problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Petr Sedláček Thank you for replying. I could understand about it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast response.
With the following

```
var payload = {"ConversationPost":{"Artifact": "/portfolioitem/capability/"+objId,"Text": post}};
  var method = "POST";
  var options = optionsPost_(method, payload);
```

and

```
var options={
    headers: { "ZSESSIONID": rallyApiKey },
    payload: payload,
    method: method,
    contentType:"application/json"
  };
```

It gives me

Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '{' but saw 'h' [ chars read = >>>h<<< ]

If I change it to

```
var options={
        headers: { "ZSESSIONID": rallyApiKey },
        payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
        method: method,
        contentType:"application/json"
      };
```

It gives me

Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '}' but saw ',' [ chars read = >>>{"headers":{"ZSESSIONID":"_ycHaCSd2QZSf8kbkQ0R1yhjohUvSzUYas0caApHt2A"},<<< ]

Only documentation I use is this:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#ConversationPost

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any difference but this actually started working.
I believe the problem was caused by combination of mistakes. I removed one problem but perhaps add another one.
Here is a code which works.

```
function createPost(objId, post) {
  objId = '313878829908';
  post = "<p>MindMap:Hello from GAS.</p>"
  var url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/conversationpost/create";
  var payload = {'ConversationPost':{'Artifact': '/portfolioitem/capability/'+objId,'Text': post}};
  var method = 'POST';
  //var options = optionsPost_(method, payload);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, optionsPost_(method, payload));
  var content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  content.CreateResult.Errors.forEach(error => Logger.log(error));
}


function optionsPost_(method, payload) {
  var rallyApiKey = "";
  if (rallyApiKey != "") {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("RallyApiKey", rallyApiKey);
  } else {
    rallyApiKey = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("RallyApiKey");
  }

  if (rallyApiKey == null) return null;

  var options={
    'headers': {'ZSESSIONID': rallyApiKey },
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
    'method': method,
    'contentType':'application/json'
  };
  return options;
}
```

Thanks Tanaike for your help. I really appreciate it.